# Android emulator appears as a small box in the top left corner of the window

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

It's my screenshot。
I don't know what happened. I tried to control DPI with the system, but I found that it would make the font very fuzzy.

---

I tested setting graphics to software-gles2.0, but it didn't work.
[enter this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl2C5.png)

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show. Can you add some clarification?

Comment: Can you help me?